# Why does KafkaUtils.createStream fail with "error: overloaded method value createStream with alternatives"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Why does the following line with `KafkaUtils.createStream`

```
val reciver = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String , StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics).map(_._2)
```

give me `error: overloaded method value createStream with alternatives:`?

```
error: overloaded method value createStream with alternatives:
(jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,keyTypeClass: Class[String],valueTypeClass: Class[String],keyDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder],valueDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder],kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String,String],topics: java.util.Map[String,Integer],storageLevel: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairReceiverInputDStream[String,String] <and> (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,kafkaParams: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String],topics: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int],storageLevel: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder], implicit evidence$4: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream[(String, String)]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String], scala.collection.immutable.Set[String])
       KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

> cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String], scala.collection.immutable.Set[String])

Mind the types as they don't match what [KafkaUtils.createStream](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$) supports.

You seem to be the closest to the following:

```
createStream[K, V, U <: Decoder[_], T <: Decoder[_]](
    ssc: StreamingContext,
    kafkaParams: Map[String, String],
    topics: Map[String, Int],
    storageLevel: StorageLevel)(/** implicits removed */): ReceiverInputDStream[(K, V)]
```

and your `topics` is of type `Set` not `Map` (!)

Use the official [KafkaWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala) example for support.